# Combinations where $n < k$.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

DISCLAIMER: I might not be using the correct terms for what I'm trying to explain, sorry about that.

The problem is, there are $28$ chairs and $19$ people, how many permutations are possible? (The order of the people is important) 
Now I reckon to get the amount of the combinations of the $9$ empty chairs is $\binom{28}{9} = \frac{28!}{(28-9)!\cdot 9!}$ - am I correct so far? For every one of those combinations, there are $19!$ ways to sort the people on the chairs, right?

So the solution to the problem would be $\binom{28}{9}\cdot 19!$. If that isn't correct so far please explain how I would go about that.

To my actual question, is there a different way (apart from writing every possible permutation, hah) to calculate this, preferably without having to know how to calculate possible groups ignoring order (as I did for the empty chairs combinations)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is solid. Here is another way of doing it:

You want to order $19$ students and $9$ indistinguishable chairs. If we pretend, for a second, that the chairs are *numbered* or something (so we actually care about their order, not just where between the students they appear, but also in relation to one another), then we just have $28$ distinguishable objects. Those can be ordered in $28!$ ways.

But the chairs *are* indistinguishable. That means that every combination that we care about is counted $9!$ times in the above argument (once for each order the chairs can be put in, within the "chair-spots" of the given ordering). Therefore the final answer is $\frac{28!}{9!}$. This quantity is also known as $_{28}P_{19}$, the same way $\binom{28}{9}$ is known as $_{28}C_9$.

Comment: Oh so the formula $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ holds true for $n < k$?

Comment: @Skilly What are you talking about, $n<k$? We have $28$ things, and we want to pick out $19$ of them, caring about their order, but not the internal order of the rest. That means $n = 28$ and $k = 19$.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I think I am slowly beginning to understand it. I've always assumed $k$ was the amount of different _places_ _things_ can go and $n$ how many different _things_ there are. I didn't think of interchanging the two, giving each student a chair instead of each chair a student in my case.

I've wrapped my head around it now, thank you for answering my question!